# Getting unwanted cropped imaged in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, layout, xamarin, view, xamarin.forms

I am new to xamarin, and am trying to understand basic positioning of views and images using xaml.

This is my xaml:

```
   <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Spacing="10"
                     x:Name="layout"
                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Button Text="StackLayout"
              VerticalOptions="Start"
              HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              Clicked="OnButtonClicked"/>
            <BoxView x:Name="myBoxView"
               Color="Yellow"
               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
            <Image x:Name="myImageView"
                   Source="circles2.jpg"
                   Aspect="AspectFit" 
                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Image x:Name="streamedImageView"
                   Source="squares.bmp"
                   Aspect="AspectFit"
                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

when the program loads, what appears is:

1. about a third of the screen is yellow
2. the "circles2.jpg" image is very small (smaller than an icon). It appears blow the yellow box.
3. the "squares.bmp" picture takes up the entire leftover space.

If i change the "circles2.jpg" to "triangles.bmp", then it takes up all the possible space horizontally possible, and the "squares.bmp" ALSO takes up as much space as horizontally possible, BUT CROPS AT THE BOTTOM OF THE SCREEN, as there is no screen left.

From all the research i done so far, I thought no cropping of views should happen - they should all find their way to fit into the screen.

What am I doing wrong?
How to make .bmp pictues stay within the screen bounds?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should understand the image control attribute:

Reference: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/

1. Fill - Stretches the image to completely and exactly fill the display area. This may result in the image being distorted.
2. AspectFill - Clips the image so that it fills the display area while preserving the aspect (ie. no distortion).
3. AspectFit - Letterboxes the image (if required) so that the entire image fits into the display area, with blank space added to the top/bottom or sides depending on the whether the image is wide or tall.

U use the AspectFit for the circles2.jpg the and use HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  the image control will long enough to put your circles2.jpg.
As the following picture shows the blue is the image control the red is your circles2.jpg
. when your circles2.jpg is large enough the image control will be distracted.

[image]

How to make .bmp pictues stay within the screen bounds?

StackLayout not suitable for you.RelativeLayout should be better：

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout/